# Can anyone explain my mysql deadlock condition?

Tags: mysql, insert, deadlock

I have a couple of questions regarding mysql dead lock.

I don't understand why below insert queries goes into deadlock condition.
Both are same query but they have different PK value and UNIQUE Key value.(must be different row)

```
TX1 : insert into deadlocktable (a, b, c, d, e, id) values (1, 1453004563, 'gerg354g3g54fgrg45g4rgt4t4t4ft4f4fff', '23r23r232rr23r23r3refserwewfswe', 22342432343, 'sdlkfj30fji0')

TX2 : insert into deadlocktable (a, b, c, d, e, id) values (1, 1453004563, 'skfjskfjsdkfjsdkfjsdkfdjskfdkffd', 'erg34geg4ewg34fg4g4g4grffsdfew', 34343t6543343, 'dfsdggrg')
```

My question goes..

1. Why TX1 requires S lock on the table when inserting ?
2. Why do they require same lock? (id 1126 page no 1121626 n bits 240 index ix_1)
3. My understanding goes

   - TX2 got X lock on the position for updating
   - TX1 wants to get same lock with the one TX2 got. So TX1 is waiting..
   - TX2 wants to get same lock with gap. Why does it need gap lock as well?

**Can anyone explain my question?**

---

mysql deadlock detector found like below

```
 (1) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 61201547464, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 3 MySQL thread id 5551783, OS thread handle 0x2b463b79d700, query id 100234460104 192.168.0.4 dbuser update 
insert into deadlocktable (a, b, c, d, e, id) values (1, 1453004563, 'gerg354g3g54fgrg45g4rgt4t4t4ft4f4fff', '23r23r232rr23r23r3refserwewfswe', 22342432343, 'sdlkfj30fji0')

(1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 1126 page no 1121626 n bits 240 index `ix_1` of table `mydb`.`deadlocktable` trx id 61201547464 lock mode S waiting Record lock, heap no 170 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 0000092f98cc6435; asc    /  d5;;
 1: len 30; hex 234385385390853853858423584235930485923085892305842390843048; asc skfjskfjsdkfjsdkfjsdkfdjskfdkf; (total 36 bytes);
 2: len 30; hex 344375894375389475894353894897539847589375893748953745738945; asc sdklfjskldfjsdkfjsklfsdklfjsdk; (total 36 bytes);

(2) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 61201547752, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000 mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 3 MySQL thread id 5550461, OS thread handle 0x2b4642d2c700, query id 100234460128 192.168.168.7 dbuser update 
insert into deadlocktable (a, b, c, d, e, id) values (1, 1453004563, 'skfjskfjsdkfjsdkfjsdkfdjskfdkffd', 'erg34geg4ewg34fg4g4g4grffsdfew', 34343t6543343, 'dfsdggrg')

(2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):

RECORD LOCKS space id 1126 page no 1121626 n bits 240 index `ix_1` of table `mydb`.`deadlocktable` trx id 61201547752 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap Record lock, heap no 170 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 0000092f98cc6435; asc    /  d5;;
 1: len 30; hex 234385385390853853858423584235930485923085892305842390843048; asc skfjskfjsdkfjsdkfjsdkfdjskfdkf; (total 36 bytes);
 2: len 30; hex 344375894375389475894353894897539847589375893748953745738945; asc sdklfjskldfjsdkfjsklfsdklfjsdk; (total 36 bytes);

 (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 1126 page no 1121626 n bits 240 index `ix_1` of table `mydb`.`deadlocktable` trx id 61201547752 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting Record lock, heap no 170 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32

 0: len 8; hex 0000092f98cc6435; asc    /  d5;;
 1: len 30; hex 234385385390853853858423584235930485923085892305842390843048; asc skfjskfjsdkfjsdkfjsdkfdjskfdkf; (total 36 bytes);
 2: len 30; hex 344375894375389475894353894897539847589375893748953745738945; asc sdklfjskldfjsdkfjsklfsdklfjsdk; (total 36 bytes);
```

Table schema is

```
CREATE TABLE `deadlocktable` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `c` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `a` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `d` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'defaultSessionId',
  `e` bigint(15) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ix_1` (`e`,`c`),
  KEY `ix_2` (`b`),
  KEY `ix_3` (`c`),
  KEY `ix_4` (`e`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

|

Comment: Try changing the isolation level to `READ-COMMITTED`

Comment: @Vatev thanks for suggestion. However I'd like to find locking mechanism when inserting  different rows at the same time. Let me try your suggestion after figuring out how it works.

Comment: @Vatev Do not advise such a workaround without mentionning the huge impacts. This is a very poor piece of advice I am afraid.